# Why don't all dates get output in "group by" SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

**Please see additional edits at the bottom.**

I am using Oracle SQL Developer to run a query to group by a date field. I am a not an advanced SQL user but have used this site to teach myself quite a bit. However, I can't seem to find an answer to the problem I'm having. One of the dates is not getting output and I'm not sure why. Can someone help?

**Query**

```
select date_added, count(*)
from table_a
where date_added >= '28-JAN-19'
group by date_added
order by date_added
```

**Results**

```
28-JAN-19 39
30-JAN-19 29
31-JAN-19 20
```

There should be a `'29-JAN-19'` date in here.

Using a `like` statement to pick up the `'29-JAN-19'` date:

**Query**

```
select date_added, count(*)
from table_a
where date_added like '%9-JAN-19%'
group by date_added
order by date_added ASC
```

**Result**

```
29-JAN-19 30
09-JAN-19 912
19-JAN-19 13
```

It sorts with `'29-JAN-19'` first which also isn't correct.

Why is it treating `'29-JAN-19'` as something else besides DATE when the DATA_TYPE = DATE for this field? I'm not seeing any trailing or leading spaces. I'm really stumped and can't seem to find any similar problems or answers. Help?

Edit: Adding table info and sample data. Note I am removing/updating values of the data that are private to our org. Here I used the Export Wizard on this table to show the first 4 columns including the date.

```
CREATE TABLE table_A 
(
  UNIQUE_ID NUMBER(20, 0) NOT NULL 
, CAMPAIGN_ID NUMBER 
, DIGITAL_VENDOR VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, DATE_ADDED DATE 
,
```

In the below link/image shows the "insert into" statements from the export wizard for both 1/29/19 (the missing output date) and 1/30/19 (which is visible in output).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPnxm.jpg)

Here is some sample data (note CAMPAIGN_ID has null values)

```
UNIQUE_ID   CAMPAIGN_ID DIGITAL_VENDOR  DATE_ADDED
359002      abc 29-JAN-19
355293      abc 30-JAN-19
355322      abc 31-JAN-19
```

Additonal edit: I was able to access the raw data files coming from the vendor. They are in CSV and when we opened them in default Excel, the dates looked normal and all similarly formatted. However, I decided to open in Notepad and that's when I see the dates are all different:

```
01/29/2019
1/29/19 
01/30/2019
2/4/19
02/05/2019
```

Now both 1/29/19 and 2/4/19 dates are not showing up in my query. So with this new info, I still have a few questions:

1. Would it be within our right to ask the vendor to send the date over in a standard format (assuming this is something that they can control) or should our tables be updated to correct for this?
2. Is there still a way to query our tables with the dates that were given?
3. Is there a way to fix this so regardless of the date formats, it will standardize?

This is a new job for me and appreciate everyone's help on how to resolve this and the best/professional way to communicate this internally or with our vendor. 
I also did not create the table nor do I have permission to edit it. I only can query the data and report on results.

Additional info:

I am adding a data dump sample of the dates as request. I see there is a difference with the first two dates I'm having an issue with but not sure what this means or how to fix. Thanks!

`DATE_ADDED  DUMP(DATE_ADDED)
    29-JAN-19   Typ=12 Len=7: 100,119,1,29,1,1,1
    04-FEB-19   Typ=12 Len=7: 100,119,2,4,1,1,1
    20-APR-17   Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,4,20,1,1,1
    21-APR-17   Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,4,21,1,1,1
    25-APR-17   Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,4,25,1,1,1`

Comment: You seem to be storing dates as strings, which would be the root of your problems.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you help me understand? The table was created before I started and the data type and values for the field are as follows. <br>COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE NULLABLE<br>
DATE_ADDED DATE Yes   The raw file that gets loaded into this table has dates in it (e.g., "1/23/2019") which then get converted to 23-JAN-19 when loaded into this table. I appreciate your help!

Comment: try `where date_added >= to_date('28/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` instead. Years have 4 digits, not 2.

Comment: @VSM Please add the table definition to your question and a few rows of sample data, so we can verify the issue.

Comment: Please let us know the result of running the following: `select count(*) from table_a where trunc(date_added) = to_date('29/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy');`

Comment: @Boneist, the results are COUNT(*) = 0.   P.S. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: @The Impaler Added table info and sample data to the original question.

Comment: Please update the query on your table to use `to_char(date_added, ‘dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss’)` to return the full date information for your date_added column. As it looks, you don’t have any data in your table with a date of 29th Jan 2019, which would explain why you’re not seeing it in your results.

Comment: @Boneist, I updated my question to add new info I found and how our vendor is sending the dates over to us. I don't have permissions to update the table as I was only tasked with querying the table and verifying what the vendor sends us match up to the counts loaded in the database. Hope my additional comments in my post can help. Thank you again!

Comment: Can you update again to include the results of querying “dump(date_added)” please? I’m wondering if there’s some corrupt data in there.

Comment: @Boneist, I'm sorry I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I did a search and found directions for using the DBA>Data Pump. When I try to use the Data Pump export wizard, I get "DBA priviledge required". If I try to export that date_added field, here are some results but don't think this is what you are looking for: Insert into TABLE_A (DATE_ADDED) values (to_date('29-JAN-19','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into TABLE_A (DATE_ADDED) values (to_date('19-JAN-19','DD-MON-RR')); I don't think this is what you are looking for. Is there a script I can run to access the info you need? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I meant, run a query like: `select date_added, dump(date_added) from table_a`

Comment: Thank you, @Boneist ! I just edited my question to add that info (not sure if you get notified - still learning). Appreciate your's and everyone's help!

Comment: It looks very much like you've got duff data in your table - I get the results of your dump if I store the date as `29/01/0019`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=540f0552c1898c17b2bb669f2c2097ef) for examples.

Comment: @Boneist - oh wow! That is not good. Would it be your recommendation that I talk to our IT guys to update something in the database or to have our vendor correct files so the date format is consistent going forward? What would be the best way to fix the data that is currently there? Would there be a way to query the data to include all dates in the meantime? I'm a little new to this so appreciate everyone's help and apologize for so many questions!

Comment: If I were you, I'd talk to your IT folks and the vendor to work out the best way of sorting the incorrect data. I assume they would ultimately go with updating the data with the wrong years, but that would be something you'd need to discuss with the powers that be!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `date_added` column is of `DATE` datatype, you would need to convert your reference date to a real date before comparing it, using `TO_DATE()`. As commented by Boneist, it is also a better practice to use 4 digits years, like :

```
select date_added, count(*)
from table_a
where date_added >= to_date('28/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by date_added
order by date_added
```

Comment: why use two digit years? 4 digits are the way to go!

Comment: @Boneist : AFAIK `yy` should work too... But I agree that it is far better to use 4 digit years, hence I updated my anwer.

Comment: Boneist and @GMB, thank you for your help. I thought it would work but it's still not pulling the 29-JAN-2019 or 1/29/2019 date. These are my results based on your query above:  'select date_added, count(*)  
from table_a  
where date_added >= to_date('28/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')  
group by date_added  
order by date_added ASC'  DATE_ADDED COUNT(*)  
28-JAN-19 39<br/>
30-JAN-19 29<br/>
31-JAN-19 20<br/><br/>
Can you also help me understand why the query pulls all dates but not 1/29/19? Thanks!

Comment: @VSM Please add the table definition to your question and a few rows of sample data, so we can verify the issue.

Comment: @GMB `yy` **might** work; it might not. That's why Oracle gave us the `rr` format mask, but even that's not ideal. If you know the date you're querying with, why not be as explicit as possible and put the 4 digits; that way Oracle doesn't have to guess and potentially get it wrong! (Having worked through Y2K, it's a pet bugbear of mine that people still use 2 digit years! *{;-) )

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section.

As requested, I tried your sample data in **Oracle 10g**, and found your initial query works as expected. I slightly changed your query to use a *standard* `DATE` literal in Oracle, instead of simple literal `VARCHAR2`, but apart from that it's the same code.

Here's the sample data provided by you (I added a couple of rows):

```
create table table_a (
  unique_id number(20,9) not null,
  campaign_id number(20,0),
  digital_vendor varchar2(100 byte),
  date_added date
);

insert into table_a (unique_id, campaign_id, digital_vendor, date_added)
  values (359002, null, 'abc', to_date('27/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
insert into table_a (unique_id, campaign_id, digital_vendor, date_added)
  values (359002, null, 'abc', to_date('28/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
insert into table_a (unique_id, campaign_id, digital_vendor, date_added)
  values (359002, null, 'abc', to_date('29/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
insert into table_a (unique_id, campaign_id, digital_vendor, date_added)
  values (355293, null, 'abc', to_date('30/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
insert into table_a (unique_id, campaign_id, digital_vendor, date_added)
  values (355322, null, 'abc', to_date('31/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

Then, your query (slightly modified) is:

```
select date_added, count(*)
from table_a
where date_added >= to_date('28/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by date_added
order by date_added
```

And the result I see is:

```
DATE_ADDED  COUNT(*)
----------  --------
2019-01-28  1
2019-01-29  1
2019-01-30  1
2019-01-31  1
```

So, it's working as expected.

My guess is the use of literal `VARCHAR2` is creating the problem. On that point, you are also using English names for months, and that can be problematic on some installations with non-default settings, or specially localised settings. I would advise to use numbers for the months while querying. When displaying dates, however, you can use any format you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like you have duff data in your table, e.g. when I create a table like:

```
create table t as
select to_date('29/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') c1 from dual union all
select to_date('04/02/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') c1 from dual union all
select to_date('20/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') c1 from dual union all
select to_date('21/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') c1 from dual union all
select to_date('25/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') c1 from dual union all
select to_date('29/01/0019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') c1 from dual union all
select to_date('04/02/0019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') c1 from dual;
```

when I select the date to show the full year, plus the dump, I see:

```
select c1, to_char(c1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') exp_c1, dump(c1) from t;

C1        EXP_C1     DUMP(C1)
--------- ---------- --------------------------------
29-JAN-19 29/01/2019 Typ=12 Len=7: 120,119,1,29,1,1,1
04-FEB-19 04/02/2019 Typ=12 Len=7: 120,119,2,4,1,1,1
20-APR-17 20/04/2017 Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,4,20,1,1,1
21-APR-17 21/04/2017 Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,4,21,1,1,1
25-APR-17 25/04/2017 Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,4,25,1,1,1
29-JAN-19 29/01/0019 Typ=12 Len=7: 100,119,1,29,1,1,1
04-FEB-19 04/02/0019 Typ=12 Len=7: 100,119,2,4,1,1,1
```

(Here's the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=540f0552c1898c17b2bb669f2c2097ef))

Note the bottom two lines, which have a year of `0019` rather than `2019` and match the output of the dump you provided. That would explain why they're not being picked up in a query looking for rows for 29th Jan 2019!